# nestjs microservices What is the best practice to manage endpoints dto?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, microservices, dto

I'm learning microservices in trying to improve my career, now I'm coding a microservices project to manage flight reservations ( I'm gonna publish here my GitHub repo if someone is interested in this framework later) and now I have a question about how we implement dto validations in endpoints...
For example, I'm coding the user controller (this is an insolated microservice project) but in the tutorial than I'm following the teacher talks about to performing all dto validations inside the api-gateway but I don't know if it is the best practice because I think every business logic/validation should be inside of every insolated microservice and the api-gateway should only manage routes and be sure if that pass the authentication before sending requests to the proper microservice.

api-gateway user.controller (following tutorial)

```
@Post()
  create(@Body() createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Observable<CreateUserI> {
    return this._clientProxyUser.send(UserMessagePattern.CREATE, createUserDto);
  }
```

api-gateway create-user.dto

```
export class CreateUserDto {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsEmail()
  email: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  password: string;
}
```

user-microservice user.controller

```
@MessagePattern(UserMessagePattern.CREATE)
  create(@Payload() createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<any> {
    return this.userService.create(createUserDto);
  }
```

user-microservice create-user.dto

```
export class CreateUserDto {
  email: string;

  password: string;
}
```

As you can see the body validation is performed in api-gateway but what if I need to apply some custom validation for example adding a custom decorator for unique email validation. What is the best practice to perform these types of validations?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

The validation should definitely be done in the microservice. Otherwise, if you have dozens of microservices, your API gateway will become a nightmare.